# Getting item of customized Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I implemented custom spinner:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
        {

                public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                            String[] objects) {
                      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }
                @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
            }

            public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                View row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
                TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                label.setText(data1[position]);

                ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                icon.setImageResource(images[position]);

                return row;
                }

       }
```

And set to a spinner like this:

```
spinner_choose_network_spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner, data1));
```

My question is how do i get the textview value of the current selected item of my spinner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Object selection = sp.getSelectedItem();
```

this returns the selected item which you can query the info from

in your adapter you need to implement `getItem(int position)`

and return the needed item, selection will be `getItem(selectedPosition)`

suppose your getItem is

```
public String getItem(int position){
return data1[position];

}
```

then `String selected = spinner.getSelectedItem();`

will return `data1[selectedPosition]`

For simplicity i would suggest you create a new object

```
public class MyCustomObject{

    String title;
    int imageResource;

}
```

and your data array will then be

```
ArrayList<MyCustomObject>data = new ArrayList<MyCustomObject>();
```

populate this array somehow

and now your row will be

```
        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row= inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, parent, false);
            TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            label.setText(data.get(position).title);

            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            icon.setImageResource(data.get(position).imageResource);

            return row;
            }
```

and then your getItem will be

```
public MyCustomObject getItem(int position){

return data.get(position);
}
```

and then your selection will be

```
MyCustomObject selection = spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

and you can see `selection.title` will be available as well as `selection.imageResource` if you need it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me, onItemSelectedListener looks like this:

```
spnrCategories.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String item = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTextViewName)).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

This is my custom spinner layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_black_18dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTextViewName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinnerImageView"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Add category1234"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTextViewNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:padding="11dp"
    android:text="(0)"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

found my solution at this site:
https://www.zoftino.com/android-spinner-custom-adapter-&-layout